# Comparing two files with awk and output non matching lines

Tags: awk

I have two files with uneven columns and I want to compare these two files and remove the matching line from file1

file 1:

```
nt1  ID420
nt1  ID42
nt56 ID6008
ht44 ID555
lt12 ID34
lt12 ID3434
ntt56 ID667
klll ID87693
```

file2

```
nt23 ID42
ht44 ID555
lt12 ID3434
```

Desired ouput:

```
nt1 ID420
nt56 ID6008
lt12 ID34
ntt56 ID667
klll ID87693
```

I have used below command from earlier post but result is not exactly matching and that is taking initial character for matching. I do not have much exp on awk commands and I need awk single line command or sed or similar shell script to get this output. Thank you well in advance:

```
awk -FS=" " 'NR==FNR {b[$0]; next} {for (x in b) if($0 ~ x) next;print $0}' file2 file1 > outputfile
```

Comment: why is "nt1  ID42" missing from the output?

Answer (score 10):

This will be the fastest:

```
grep -vFxf file2 file1
```

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file2 file1
```

If you don't care that the output is sorted, this is what [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is for:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: The `grep` attempt is nice! My first thought was using `diff` and `patch` here, however I've failed so far.. Found `diff --supress-common-lines` which can be reverted somehow, but ... still trying. Also `comm` seems interesting here.. However, your `grep` one is good! :)

Comment: My first thought was `comm`, but it requires the input files to be sorted, so the output would not be as OP requested.

Comment: I have tried grep and awk solution as suggested above.. Those are working.